# Sublime text autocomplete bug (HTML Tags)

Tags: html, text, editor

There has been a little bug with my Sublime Text 3. When I try auto-completing some HTML tags, a extra '<' is inserted before the first tag, making me have to go back and manually delete it every time I autocomplete tags. I am using build 3176 and I have tried rolling back to 3170 but the issue still occurred. The odd thing is that on my main PC, even though I have the same version of Sublime Text, the bug does not occur there. I have included images below of my issue.

Before pressing tab:

[image]

After pressing tab:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just type the short version that you want, may it be 'p' for `<p></p>` and press the tab, not enter and it will autocomplete.

Answer (score 0):

What happens is, it looks like you are using [Emmet](https://emmet.io/). You gotta give only the tag name and it completes.

Eg:

```
div→
<div></div>

a→
<a href=""></a>

link→
<link rel="stylesheet" href="" />

img→
<img src="" alt="" />
```

Try to leverage the use of Emmet this way. You have a huge list of [Cheat Sheet](https://docs.emmet.io/cheat-sheet/) to make use of too. It's really a feature and not a bug. `:)`

Comment: The autocomplete function does not pop up when only typing 'div', it only pops up when typing '<*'

Comment: @codingpenguin Looks like both the plugins are getting activated at the same time: Autocomplete and Emmet. `:(`